# Cleaning up the console command help output

Tags: php, laravel

I have quite a few laravel console commands in my applications for maintenance tasks and in the vast majority of cases, few of the default options presented by the help dialog are needed and supported by my use case. Typical help output looks like this:

```
Description:
  Do stuff

Usage:
  myapp:mycommand

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

I don't like the idea of presenting options to the user that I have no intention of supporting, so I would like to omit a bunch of these options from the `--help` text to clean up the info shown. For instance the `--no-interaction`, `--no-ansi`, `--ansi`, `--verbose` flags, etc. So far I have been unable to find any elegant (laravel) way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: i havent considered allowing artisan script access to users. I think you have to extend some of the commands and modify them that way.

Comment: To clarify, I am referring to users who are my colleagues at work who share in administrative duties with these applications. Most of the applications in question handle various integrations between systems and on the occasion that a 'user' access the system (in the sense you are thinking), it is done as an API request and is all run through laravel controllers.

Comment: Those options are populated from the `getDefaultInputDefinition` method of class `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` which is called by the same method in the class `Illuminate\Console\Application`.. I think you would have to extend one of these class and somehow get your artisan's kernel to use the new class... i highly not recommend this though as it's very hacky..

Comment: Thanks for the info, Helioarch. As you note, I was hoping to find an elegant solution and if none exists, then I'll just live with the inelegance of a cluttered help output with options that aren't relevant to the command.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `app\Console\Kernel.php` file which comes standard with the laravel installation. It extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel`.

Now, you can overwrite the constructor with the following code:

```php
    // Define a property where the keys are the command name, and the values
    // are arrays with the options that you are allowed to pass. 
    protected $optionFilters = [
        'my-command-name' => [
            'user',
            'raw',
        ]
    ];

    public function __construct(Application $app, Dispatcher $events)
    {
        parent::__construct($app, $events);

        $commands = $this->getArtisan()->all();

        foreach ($commands as $command) {
            // Now we simply loop all registered commands, and see if we should
            // apply a filter.
            if ($filter = array_get($this->optionFilters, $command->getName())) {
                $options = array_filter(
                    $command->getDefinition()->getOptions(),
                    function (\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption$option) use ($filter) {
                        return in_array($option->getName(), $filter);
                });
                // Set the new options to the command.
                $command->getDefinition()->setOptions($options);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if you had previously defined a command like:

```php
protected $signature = 'my-command-name {--user} {--raw} {--type}';
```

Running the above loop would have omitted the `{--type}` from the command.

I did notice some side effects though when removing options from Laravel's own artisan commands (like the `php artisan help` command which threw some errors when i removed the `--format` option). So you'll have to check some of that out.

> There's a `getArguments()` and `setArguments()` as well that could be used for omitting arguments like `{user?}` or `{user=foo}` (options start with `--` in the command definition, arguments do not).